# Howto trigger Progressbar from a function in the data access layer

Tags: progress-bar

I have a function in a class: for each fetched record in this function I write the record to a file, I also want to add the value/count of this fetched record in my progressbar, BUT this progressbar exists in the form page and the function exists in my class, I call the function in the formpage

here is a part of this function

```
        this.path_to_file =
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExportDir"] +
DateTime.Now.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings
["Export_FileName"]) + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings
["Export_Extension"];


        FileStream fm = new FileStream
           (this.path_to_file, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite,
FileShare.ReadWrite);

        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fm, Encoding.Default);

        List<Export> exportRecords = null;

        exportRecords = ExportList();
        try
        {
            int i = 0;
           foreach (Export ex in exportRecords)
           {
               sw.Write(ex.ExportLine());
              sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
              sw.Flush();
               i++;
           }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
           Log.Write(exc.Message);
        }
```

it returns strings

Comment: Could you confirm whether your application is using any Business entities before reaching the DAL, and how the form is triggering this write?

Comment: public override List<Export> ExportList() is a override List<> 
and in this List I call another list (here starts thje data access layer) that fetches the real data from the database with oledbdatareader. Yes I use Buss. entities

Answer (score 1):

Have your class raise an event with the progress, and your form update accordingly.

Or better yet, do it on a background thread:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx